# How could large scale mining operations render an arid region unlivable?

Tags: science-based, planets, habitability, mining

A story I am working on sees the characters returning to a fairly arid planet that was mined heavily by an interplanetary corporation. This left most of the planet uninhabitable and forced the local population (that survived) to migrate from the region. In this story, it is fairly well established that humanity can to a degree overcome resource limitations of a regions (such as access to water and food) due to this corporation's wide influence.

I want to know, what effects could aggressive large-scale mining have on large portions of a planet that would leave it unfit for human habitation without relying on limiting access to resources (such as water)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mine tailings**

The first thought was about all the acids that are used to extract the base elements from the ore. However, they would be deadly, but they will form a localised pollution. On the other hand before the leaching step the ores are usually crushed until they form a fine powder. Your planet might be rich in heavy metals that would be no longer useful in future industrial processes, mercury and lead could be the first candidates you could add cadmium. All the unwanted heavy metals could form toxic micro-crystals embedded in the grains of the mine tailings. Constantly blown by the winds the powder of such tailings could easily render wide areas uninhabitable.

BTW This is nothing exotic fine powdered mine tailings are already a serious problem here on Earth, the abundance of heavy metals on your planet would just make them a little bit deadlier.

Comment: Coal mine tailings are moderately radioactive and I suspect that could be true of many other kinds of mining as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's already here on Earth, no further explanation needed. [Surface-mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_mining) leaves large areas of surface barren and uninhabitable. It's the easiest, cheapest form of mining and the only one which is infinitely scalable so it's kinda obvious that mining other planets would be performed using this method.

Calling it environmentally-unfriendly is an understatement, surface-mining removes the environment altogether.

Your population would have been first forcefully removed by the corporation to make room for bulldozers and after the ore is gone there would be nothing to return to: no soil, no vegetation, no water. Just dirt. Vast flat areas of dirt interwoven with mountain-sized heaps of dirt. If there was water before, now it would also be nothing but a medium leaching toxic minerals and contaminating everything it touches.

It takes very serious effort here on Earth to merely contain post-mining areas, not even mentioning full rehabilitation. Simply because the dirt is not a soil and nothing can grow there without costly assistance. The exposed dirt with no vegetation means that any wind causes dust storms. So even if a neighboring area was spared (eg. because there was nothing valuable close to the surface enough) and the refugees relocated there, it would also eventually be contaminated by the fallout, situation slowly becoming worse year after year even decades after the mining company had left.

Answer (score 2):

- Mining can disrupt the flow of the underground aquifer, resulting in wells drying up or being polluted/made unfit for human use
- Mining can leave wastes around, which are not exactly life friendly. For example it has been found that ancient copper miners polluted the places where they operated and refined the ore with large amounts of arsenic, as a result of the refining operation
- Mining will use other local resources, altering the local equilibrium. As an example, if you cut all the trees to get beams and whatever else for your mines, that will have an impact.

Answer (score 1):

They cracked a underground volcano and triggered a massive eruption with an ash cloud from radioactive materials (the kind they were mining perhaps?) that covered the planet/region. Leading to a nuclear/volcanic winter.

Other vulcanic options are triggering lahars (a large hot mudflow) from a compressed mud layer under a rock layer they breached. This mudflow can continue flowing for a long time and makes the place completely uninhabitable.

Answer (score 1):

Many fictional stories employ the device that mining or environmentally unsound activity has disturbed a chthonic (i.e. underground) species of "monsters" who are dangerous, causing them to be more active and threaten human life forcing humans to abandon an area. *See, e.g*., *Godzilla*, *Dune*, *Darling In The Franxx*, *Blue Seed*, and *Dragons: The Nine Realms*.

This particular story seems ripe for this trope.